# PHP script to read CSV file returning echo more than once

Tags: php, csv, schedule

I've pulled together a radio schedule PHP script to read a CSV file and post the results on a website depending on time and date. However, it appears to be posting twice.

Here is the script:

```
<?php
// Step 1: Replace 'data.csv' with the path to your CSV file
$csvFile = 'schedule.csv';

// Step 2: Read CSV and store its contents in an array
if (($handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r')) !== false) {
    $csvData = [];
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
        $csvData[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    die("Error opening CSV file.");
}

// Step 3: Get the current day and time
$currentDay = date('l'); // l gives the full textual representation of the day (e.g., "Monday")
$currentHour = date('H'); // H gives the hour in 24-hour format (e.g., "13" for 1 PM)
// Adjust hour offset below.
$Hour = $currentHour+1;

// Step 4: Filter the array based on the current day and time
$filteredData = [];
foreach ($csvData as $row) {
    // Assuming that your CSV file has a "Day" column and a "Time" column
    $day = $row[0];
    $time = intval($row[1]);
$program_name= $row[2];
$program_when= $row[2];
$program_img= $row[4];

    // Check if the row matches the current day and time
   if ($day === $currentDay && $Hour >= $time) {
        $filteredData[] = $row;
    }
}

// Step 5: Display the filtered data with CSS classes for each row
if (count($filteredData) > 0) {


    foreach ($filteredData as $row) {
     

echo "<div class='row'>";
echo "<div class='col-5'>";
echo "<img src='$row[4]' width='90' height='90' border='0'>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class='col-7'>";
echo "<h3>$row[2]<br>$row[3]</h3>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
 
    }
} else {
    echo 'Not available.';
}
```

Here is the data I was testing in the CSV file:

```
Friday,12,MMV,until 1pm,top_mmv.png
Friday,13,MMV,until 2pm,top_mmv.png
Friday,14,MMV,until 3pm,top_mmv.png
Friday,15,MMV,until 4pm,top_mmv.png
```

But when it gets to 2pm on a Friday it posts both the 1pm row AND the 2pm row. What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: to improve your question, add the csv content as well because then it is easier to reproduce. you could do even further and have it as data already within the script on top so that this can be executed and reproduced in one go. compare [mre] and I'm sure you'll get better feedback as well.

Comment: _"Here is the data I was testing in the CSV file:"_ - is that supposed to be one single row from the CSV? Or is it missing line breaks?

Comment: I fixed (I HOPE) the csv input file as I assume there must be newlines in there somewhere. Or am I Wrong

Comment: ___But when it gets to 2pm on a Friday it posts both the 1pm row AND the 2pm row___ Not with this code, although there is quite a bit of unnecessary data manipulation in there

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify the conditions under which you want to collect the data,

```php
if ($day === $currentDay && $Hour >= $time) {
```

e.g. now the current time is 14 (+1 hour is your adjustment)

$Hour >= $time

```
15 >= time from first line of csv is 12 - true
15 >= time from second line of csv is 13 - true
15 >= time from third line of csv is 14 - true
15 >= 15 - true
```

I think you can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The code you show us does not actually demonstrate the issue you mention?

However you can simplify that code and remove the need for 2 arrays and make the code easier to read and maintain like this.

```
$currentDay = date('l'); // l gives the full textual representation of the day (e.g., "Monday")
$currentHour = date('H'); // H gives the hour in 24-hour format (e.g., "13" for 1 PM)
// Adjust hour offset below.
$Hour = $currentHour+1;

// The input file
$csvFile = 'schedule.csv';

// Step 2: Read CSV and process the output
if (($handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r')) !== false) {
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
        $day = $row[0];
        $time = intval($row[1]);
    
        // Check if the row matches the current day and time
        if ($day === $currentDay && $Hour >= $time) {
            echo "<div class='row'>\n";
                echo "  <div class='col-5'>\n";
                    echo "      <img src='$row[4]' width='90' height='90' border='0'>\n";
                echo "  </div>\n";
                echo "  <div class='col-7'>\n";
                    echo "      <h3>$row[2]<br>$row[3]</h3>\n";
                echo "  </div>\n";
            echo "</div>\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {
    die("Error opening CSV file.");
}
```

And using this data

```
Friday,12,MMV,until 1pm,top_mmv.png
Friday,13,MMV,until 2pm,top1_mmv.png
Friday,14,MMV,until 3pm,top2_mmv.png
Friday,15,MMV,until 4pm,top3_mmv.png
```

And running the code between 14:00 and 14:59 The output is

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-5'>
      <img src='top_mmv.png' width='90' height='90' border='0'>
  </div>
  <div class='col-7'>
      <h3>MMV<br>until 1pm</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-5'>
      <img src='top1_mmv.png' width='90' height='90' border='0'>
  </div>
  <div class='col-7'>
      <h3>MMV<br>until 2pm</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-5'>
      <img src='top2_mmv.png' width='90' height='90' border='0'>
  </div>
  <div class='col-7'>
      <h3>MMV<br>until 3pm</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is anything is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

> But when it gets to 2pm on a Friday it posts both the 1pm row AND the 2pm row. What am I doing wrong, please?

From the date of your question, 2023-07-28 13:21:42Z, and the (timezone?) offset you apply

```php
$currentHour = date('H'); // H gives the hour in 24-hour format (e.g., "13" for 1 PM)
// Adjust hour offset below.
$Hour = $currentHour+1;
```

For the condition it is a simple calculation error:

```php
$Hour >= $time
```

The $time is from the CSV data, and $Hour=14 is greater or equal than 12, 13 and 14. So it will display erroneously as the show until 1 PM is still displayed but not running/scheduled any longer.

So the obvious fix is to remove the offset at the hour and compare against the *end* time which is the one hour frame of $time:

```php
$currentHour <= $time
```